# Postman Fails to make Post call to amazon kinesis

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to call the liststream method of amazon kinesis via postman but i get socket connection timedout.

I have used sts asume role for access and secret key.
The role in question has full access to kinesis streams.
When i curl the url endpoint i get a connection established message but when i hit any method via java sdk or postman i fail to get a response
Postman results(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzQzE.png)